# Query Multiple Collection of PgVector using Langchain

Tags: python, py-langchain, openaiembeddings, pgvector

I have multiple auth_id

```
auth_id_1 = "123"
auth_id_2 = "456"
```

Now I am using PGVector method to load data from it based on the collection

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vector_store = PGVector(
        embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings(
            openai_api_key=openai_key, max_retries=MAX_RETRIES),
        collection_name=auth_id,
        connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING,
        distance_strategy=DISTANCE_STRATEGY
    )
    return vector_store
```

Can I pass Multiple auth_id in collection name, To Query Multiple User's Files